# celery + rabbitmq on Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery, docker-compose

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [How to build docker cluster with celery and RabbitMQ in 10 minutes](https://medium.com/@tonywangcn/how-to-build-docker-cluster-with-celery-and-rabbitmq-in-10-minutes-13fc74d21730).

Followed the tutorial, although I did changed the following files.
My `docker-compose.yml` file looks as follows:

```
version: '2'                                                                    

services:
    rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq
    environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user                           
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass                          
        - HOSTNAME=rabbitmq                                     
        - RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbitmq 
    ports: 
        - "5672:5672"  # we forward this port because it's useful for debugging
        - "15672:15672"  # here, we can access rabbitmq management plugin                                    


worker:
    build:
    context: .                                              
    dockerfile: Dockerfile                                  
    volumes:                                                        
        - .:/app                                                
    links:                                                          
        - rabbit                                                
    depends_on:                                                     
        - rabbit
```

`test_celery/celery.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery                                                       

app = Celery('test_celery',broker='amqp://user:pass@rabbit:5672//',backend='rpc://', include=['test_celery.tasks'])
```

and `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6       
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt  
ADD ./test_celery /app/ 
WORKDIR /app/   
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  
ENTRYPOINT celery -A test_celery worker --loglevel=info
```

I run the code with the following commands(My OS is Ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo docker-compose build   
sudo docker-compose scale worker=5 
sudo docker-compose up
```

The output on screen looks something like this:

```
rabbit_1  | closing AMQP connection <0.501.0> (172.19.0.6:60470 -> 172.19.0.7:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'admin'):
rabbit_1  | client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
rabbit_1  | 
rabbit_1  | =WARNING REPORT==== 8-Jun-2017::03:34:15 ===
rabbit_1  | closing AMQP connection <0.479.0> (172.19.0.6:60468 -> 172.19.0.7:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'admin'):
rabbit_1  | client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
rabbit_1  | 
rabbit_1  | =WARNING REPORT==== 8-Jun-2017::03:34:15 ===
rabbit_1  | closing AMQP connection <0.366.0> (172.19.0.4:44754 -> 172.19.0.7:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'admin'):
rabbit_1  | client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
rabbit_1  | 
rabbit_1  | =WARNING REPORT==== 8-Jun-2017::03:34:15 ===
rabbit_1  | closing AMQP connection <0.359.0> (172.19.0.4:44752 -> 172.19.0.7:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'admin'):
rabbit_1  | client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
worker_1  | [2017-06-08 03:34:19,138: INFO/MainProcess] missed heartbeat from celery@f77048a9d801
worker_1  | [2017-06-08 03:34:24,140: INFO/MainProcess] missed 
heartbeat from celery@79aa2323a472
worker_1  | [2017-06-08 03:34:24,141: INFO/MainProcess] missed heartbeat from celery@93af751ed1b5
```

Then in the same directory I run

```
python -m test_celery.run_tasks
```

and the output from this gives me:

a `kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: timed out` error which I am not sure how to fix and get the same output as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As the output and error report, "client unexpectedly closed TCP connection" , "kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: timed out", it seems that RabbitMQ didn't start as expected. Could you run the command "docker ps -a" to check what's the status of Rabbit container? If exited , "docker logs container-id" will print out logs of Rabbit container.

Comment: Status is shown as 'up a minute ago' and the logs show the a bunch of messages along the lines of: =INFO REPORT==== 8-Jun-2017::04:00:21 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.398.0> (172.19.0.3:33112 -> 172.19.0.2:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Jun-2017::04:00:21 ===
connection <0.398.0> (172.19.0.3:33112 -> 172.19.0.2:5672): user 'admin' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

Comment: i dont know if its useful, but after doing `docker-compose down` and rebuilding I get: ERROR: for dockerclusterwithceleryandrabbitmq_worker_4  Cannot start service worker: network dockerclusterwithceleryandrabbitmq_default not found
ERROR: for dockerclusterwithceleryandrabbitmq_worker_5  Cannot start service worker: network dockerclusterwithceleryandrabbitmq_default not found
ERROR: for dockerclusterwithceleryandrabbitmq_worker_1  Cannot start service worker: network dockerclusterwithceleryandrabbitmq_default not found
...

Comment: change "rabbit" in celery.py to ip of your localhost. https://github.com/plantpark/docker-cluster-with-celery-and-rabbitmq. The same code here works well for me.

Comment: If I changed rabbit to localhost I get: `[2017-06-08 11:26:45,454: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
worker_1  | Trying again in 6.00 seconds...`

Comment: @jorge ok, my fault. Not localhost, ip of your machine that running this service.

Comment: In case someone finds it like I did: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/ "Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias." = define own network, then you can just use container name